# OneNote.com just shows a blank page

Tags: webapps

When I go to http://www.onenote.com/ I just get a completely blank page, no errors, nothing.  If I look at the page source I see lots of HTML.  Any idea what's happening?  I have Java installed, using Mozilla on Ubuntu 16.04, everything's up to date.

Comment: Indeed. I don't know why but perhaps it's the website's owner not wanting you to see that page from a competing OS. It opens fine in Chrome though.

Answer (score 1):

**For https://www.onenote.com/**

- Broken: Ubuntu 17.10 (Daily) + Firefox 55.0.2
- Works : Ubuntu 17.10 (Daily) + Konqueror 5.0.97
- Works : Ubuntu 17.10 (Daily) + Firefox
  55.0.2 + user-agent switcher set to Windows and Chrome.

There are loads of switchers, but this is the one I used:

https://mybrowseraddon.com/useragent-switcher.html?v=0.1.9&type=install

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer? If that's the case please explain how it *answers the question at hand*. Otherwise this is only a listing of (un-)supported browsers.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I read this as recommending to either use a different browser or cause the unsupported browser one is using to report itself as being a different browser that is supported. I wouldn't delete this answer, and I think it is even useful in its current form, but I do hope it gets expanded to make the recommendations clearer. Bastiat, I recommend you **[edit]** this question to address David Foerster's concerns by expanding it with an explicit recommendation and explanation of how it fixes the problem.